# Azure Synapse Web activity paging

Tags: azure, pipeline, azure-synapse-analytics

I'm using a web activity in Azure Synapse to retrieve subscriptions from https://management.azure.com/subscriptions and subsequently processing each subscription.
The response containing 1000 data objects in JSON format indicates additional objects available by returning a 'nextLink' attribute.
However, the UI does not offer any option for paging in the web activity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMIoA.png)

I could circumvent the problem by applying procedural programming techniques (loop until 'nextLink' is empty)
But I would expect Azure to offer an implicit paging mechanism in the Web Activity but am not able to find it.